# HTTP POST a JSON array using PHP/CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to send a JSON array to an API via HTTP POST, get a response and print it.

I tried using cURL to do so, but it doesn't seem to work.
I simply get zero response, a blank page.

My request:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "login" => "myLogin",
    "password" => "myPassword",
    "id" => "12345",
    "tag" => "test"
    );                                                                    

$json_data = json_encode($data);                                                                                   


$ch = curl_init('URL/api/mylogin');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($output);

echo $result;

?>
```

The response I should be getting:

```
{"status": 200, "message": "OK", "login_key": "abcdefh532h235yh"}
```

any idea why I'm not getting any response?

(this works ok when I manually test it using a test REST client)

Comment: Try `echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` after curl_exec and see what it says.

Comment: did you try my solution? @rani

Comment: Wayne Whitty - I did it, and it says "0"... not sure at all what this means.

Comment: Developer - I did try it, but it didn't work, I still got blank response

Answer (score 1):

Try this @rani now you can get response.

```
    $url = 'URL/api/mylogin';
    $ch = curl_init($url);

 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myLogin'.':'.'myPassword'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $response;
```

or pass key as a password in `CURLOPT_USERPWD`.

Comment: This returns a blank page as well.

Btw I'm actually not sure that the server I'm querying supports "CURLOPT_USERPWD".

Comment: @Rani..ohh then make sure first?

Comment: Can't the username and password be passed at regular key:value ?